# Is the company accountant allowed to C.C my boss on an email about my tax information?

Tags: work-experience

The accountant for the place I work at got all snippy with me because I asked her what I had wrote down for my State with holdings. Didn't want to give it to me. When she finally does she carbon copies her boss/mom and my boss on an email with some of my tax information in it. Because she was mad at my email. Is this legal?

Comment: Legal questions are out of scope here, so as written, this will be closed.

Comment: It is not your accountant

Answer (score 4):

Whether it is legal or not is almost irrelevant. It would cost you far more to pursue a legal option that you could possibly gain as a result.

As the accounting person she has the the ability to thoroughly mess you over if you make her angry. I had a friend one time who annoyed the a payroll clerk at his place of work and then had to spend several months dealing with IRS to fix the W2 form that had his income doubled.

Further this person works for her mother. In reality how much leverage do you have at that place to fix her attitude. The correct answer to that is zero.
Personally I would see if the two managers call her out for her unprofessional behavior and if they do not, then I would move along to a more professionally run company or if you otherwise want to stay, then apologize to her for bothering her and stay out of her way as much as possible. (Yes I know you did nothing wrong, too bad, so sad, her mother is her boss, you must keep this person happy.) This is not a winnable battle unless **her mother** agrees with you.

Comment: I would note that if you're going to leave, then when you do, maybe mention this unprofessional behaviour as one of the things that drove you to it. But only if you think it won't burn bridges in doing so / upset the person you're discussing it with that may be a future reference.

Answer (score 2):

How much harm was done to you, really? Realistically, your boss already knows most of your salary info, and her mommy is going to ignore it.

Let her be petulant if she can't be professional. Don't descend to her level.